# How to change ::after of child element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a parent and some child elements but I can't change their CSS directly. So, I'm trying to change my child's CSS inside the css of my parent element. Example:

```
.parent {
     & .child {
          ::after {
               width: 100%;
               background-color: black;
          }
     }
}
```

This is just a simple example to illustrate that I want to change my child `::after` pseudo-element.

How can I do this?

Comment: Well nesting css like that doesn't work without postprocessing so I assume you're using SCSS or LESS. In normal CSS you would simply write `.parent .child:after{...}` Make sure to put it after the other styles have loaded so it will override them and change.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BryceHowitson you're totally right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Bryce points out, you are not writing CSS here, you are writing in a CSS pre-processor language, which browsers cannot understand.

The [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/) you wrote means:

> The `::after` pseudo-element of an element with both the `.parent` class and the `.child` class.

That is what the ampersand (`&`) means in SCSS: both the previous selector **and** what follows.

So literally you should translate that to the following CSS:

```
.parent.child::after {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Note that there is no space between `.parent` and `.child`. This is the way to express this ***and*** behaviour of requiring both classes.

However, you probably meant:

> The `::after` pseudo-element of a `.child` element of a `.parent` element.

This should be

```
.parent > .child::after {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Or more loosely (allowing any number of elements in the hierarchy between `.parent` and `.child`):

```
.parent .child::after {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

(Note the space between `.parent` and `.child`)

Comment: I don't know why my question got downvoted. But thank you, you gave me a class! The point is that I'm totally new on CSS and front-end design so I don't get the difference between those things. Your answer worked like a charm. Thanks a lot to you and to Bryce.